# print HtmlAnchor text inside <span> tags

Tags: htmlunit

I have the following HtmlAnchor

```
<a href="/property/tx/coldspring/77331/82-bradford-ln/167035284">
 <span itemprop="streetAddress">SOMENUMBER Bradford Ln</span>, 
 <span itemprop="addressLocality">Coldspring</span>, 
 <span itemprop="addressRegion">TX</span> 
 <span itemprop="postalCode">77331</span>
</a>
```

When I print `htmlAnchor.getTextContent()` It's not printing the text inside the `span` tags. How can I get the whole text printed?

Comment: Have done some tests, looks like everything works correct. Can you please post the output of htmlAnchor.asXml() to reproduce your sample with all the details.

Comment: The mistake was on my part, the xpath was getting <a> which did not contain the text